# Insert random url into src= ( PHP )

Tags: php, video, random

I'm trying to display a random YouTube video on refresh of my page but it doesn't work. I have the PHP that is working here:

```
<?php 
$video_array = array 
('http://www.youtube.com/embed/rMNNDINCFHg', 
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg', 
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg'); 
$total = count($video_array); 
$random = (mt_rand()%$total); 
$video = "$video_array[$random]"; 
?>
```

that I'm trying to put into this:

```
<iframe width='1006' height='421' src='<?php echo $video; ?>' frameborder='0'       allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but it seems like it's not working. Could you guys help me out? Thanks! I've been looking for 2 hours and got the same bad results.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$video_array = array 
('http://www.youtube.com/embed/rMNNDINCFHg', 
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg', 
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg'); 
shuffle($video_array);
$video = $video_array[0]; 
?>
```

then you can just embed it.

```
<iframe width='1006' height='421' src='<?php echo $video; ?>' frameborder='0'       allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what why you are doing this:

```
$video = "$video_array[$random]";
```

Make that look like this

```
$video = $video_array[$random];
```

Comment: thanks , i fixed that but still not working , it shows me http://gyazo.com/aec9fc14420735a434bd794e72761de2

Comment: add var_dump($video); after you set it and then look at the source of your webpage. At the top should be the contents of $value and you can see whats wrong.

Comment: I tried putting var_dump($video); and seen no change/nothing appear in the source of my webpage what's wrong :S

Comment: Maybe you're caching the old page?

Comment: That tells me that wherever the code is that has the <iframe> is doesn't know what $value is. Can you show if they are in seperate files?

Comment: index.html (HTML FILE) doesn't know what PHP is. Anything with <php> in it needs to be a .php file.

Comment: oh i'm dumb i guess.. ahah thanks but how would i put that into the space i want my video to be in the html page?

Comment: That's a whole 'nother' question

Comment: You can just change the extension from `.html` to `.php`. It will still work correctly but it will parse the `php` as `php` and not plain `html`!

Comment: I get : file:///C:/Users/Olivier/Documents/FunClipz2/%3C?php%20echo%20$video;%20?%3E is not found

Answer (score 0):

I'm all about one-liners :x

```
<?php echo $video_array[rand(0,(count($video_array)-1))]; ?>
```

Other answers thus far are not reducing count()... this will cause errors when it grabs the highest number, as the beginning index==0

Comment: You're wrong about the `count()` in both the posters and others answers. In your example you set min/max values where as in all others they do not. Instead they're calculating a large random number and using modulo: `randomNumber % totalLinks`. Basically in both cases with three links in `$video_array` both ways will output `0`, `1`, or `2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<?php 
$video_array = array 
('http://www.youtube.com/embed/rMNNDINCFHg', 
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg', 
'http://www.youtube.com/embed/bDF6DVzKFFg'); 
$total = count($video_array); 
$random = rand(0, $total-1); 
$video = $video_array[$random]; 
?>
```